# String sorting not available in elastic search?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to sort a 'prod_name' which is string in elastic mapping. but this is not working. Any reference to make it work?

Comment: show your code!!

Comment: @KRIPS. Thank you for reply. I made it work by 'keyword' type in mapping instead of 'string'.

Comment: Then delete your question, or post your solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by 'keyword' type in mapping instead of 'string'.